# Localize datetime (timezone aware) from timezone offset

Tags: python, pytz, python-dateutil, python-datetime

I have a UTC timestamp and a timezone offset timestamp (both in milliseconds):

```
utc_time = 1394452800000
timezoneoffset = -14400000
```

If I wanted to get the `datetime` I would do :

```
print datetime.utcfromtimestamp(utc_time/1000)
>>>2014-03-10 12:00:00
```

**How can I localize this datetime but also the final object be timezone aware?**

If I divide `timezoneoffset`, -14400000/(3600*1000) = -4 (hours). So the final output should be:

```
>>>2014-03-10 08:00:00-04:00
```

---

My try:

```
from pytz import timezone
from dateutil.tz import tzoffset

utc_time = 1394452800000
timezoneoffset = -14400000

tzinfooff = tzoffset(None, timezoneoffset/1000)

print timezone(tzinfooff).localize( datetime.utcfromtimestamp(utc_time/1000) )

>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dionysis_lorentzos/Desktop/cmdline copy.py", line 25, in <module>
    print timezone(tzinfo2).localize( datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time/1000) ).isoformat()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 162, in timezone
    if zone.upper() == 'UTC':
AttributeError: 'tzoffset' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

Comment: `08:00:00-04:00`? or `12-4`?

Comment: `timezone` doesn't take an offset; I am not sure that there is any `pytz` callable that does.

Comment: @zhangxaochen the `utc_time` timestamp is in UTC timezone not the local one (if I understand correctly your question).

Comment: @MartijnPieters so there is no possible workaround ?

Comment: I didn't say that. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use *just* the [`dateutil.tz.tzoffset()` type](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-8bf499d888b70bc300c6c8820dc123326197c00f); `pytz.timezone` only takes *names*, not `dateutil.tz` objects.

The `.localize()` method is only needed for `pytz`-supplied timezones as they contain historic offsets as well, and they need to be applied to a `datetime` object using a little more care than just `.replace()` can do.

If the timestamp is a UNIX epoch value in UTC, then use `fromtimestap` with the timezone as a second argument:

```
>>> print datetime.fromtimestamp(utc_time/1000, tzinfooff)
2014-03-10 08:00:00-04:00
```

Or you could *translate* from UTC, using `datetime.astimezone()`:

```
>>> from dateutil.tz impor tzutc
>>> dt_utc = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(utc_time/1000).replace(tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> print dt_utc.astimezone(tzinfooff)
2014-03-10 08:00:00-04:00
```

Comment: thanks! May I suggest: `print datetime.utcfromtimestamp((utc_time+timezoneoffset)/1000).replace(tzinfo=tzinfooff)
>>>2014-03-10 08:00:00-04:00`. Or no?

Comment: @Diolor: in that case you are not attaching a timezone, you are translating to a different timezone. Set it up with the UTC timezone then translate with `datetime.astimezone()`.

Comment: I would go with `datetime.fromtimestamp()`, thank you

Comment: @Diolor: I quite agree. :-)

Comment: it is incorrect to use `local_dt = utcfromtimestamp(ts).replace(tzinfo=local_tz)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: The question was unclear as to what the OP was trying to do; a lot of comments have been removed since. The OP is using the `fromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch, timezone)` method now.

Comment: I'm talking about your answer that is incorrect based on the question (I don't see any edits of the question)

Comment: Yes, there was a different interpretation of what the OP was trying to do; the answer tried to address different interpretations.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: there is no interpretation. The code is incorrect.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: No need to be so harsh; I am working from recollection here.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Removed the offending part for you.

Comment: +2. I didn't mean to be harsh.

Answer (score 1):

To convert POSIX timestamp to an timezone-aware datetime object in a timezone specified by its utc offset, you could create an aware utc datetime object and convert it to the fixed offset timezone:

```
from datetime import datetime

utc_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(utc_time * 1e-3, utc)
dt = utc_dt.astimezone(FixedOffset(timezoneoffset * 1e-3 / 60, None))

print(dt.isoformat(' '))
# -> 2014-03-10 08:00:00-04:00
```

where `utc` and `FixedOffset` are defined in [`datetime` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta

class FixedOffset(tzinfo):
    """Fixed offset in minutes east from UTC."""

    def __init__(self, offset, name):
        self.__offset = timedelta(minutes = offset)
        self.__name = name

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return self.__offset

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return self.__name

    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)

utc = FixedOffset(0, "UTC")
```