# How can I use a dateutil.tz.tz.tzoffset to localize a timezone naive datetime created using strptime?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz, python-dateutil

How can I use an object, which is of type dateutil.tz.tz.tzoffset, to localize a timezone naive datetime object with correct timezone and DST info so it can be properly converted to UTC? Alternatively, how do I convert dateutil.tz.tz.tzoffset to a pytz.timezone?

I have been unable to find good information on localizing a datetime object using dateutil.tz.tz.tzoffset object. See below for a few of the better articles I've reviewed.

Background Info:

I am dealing with numerous date strings, most of which have no timezone information. In some cases the time is in GMT, in others it's local. I have to first determine the timezone of the device creating these various logs, then parse the various date strings, add the add timezone if it's a local time, and finally convert it to UTC.

I almost have this all working, except the only reliable way to determine the TimeZone is from a text file which has the date in the format of EDT, IST, etc so I have used the top up-voted post at the below link to accomplish this using dateutil's parser.parse() function and sending it a dict for it's tzinfos argument. ([Parsing date/time string with timezone abbreviated name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703546/parsing-date-time-string-with-timezone-abbreviated-name-in-python))

However, this leaves me with a DateTime which has a tzinfo type=dateutil.tz.tz.tzoffset. That's ok by me, except then I need to use this tzinfo to localize the strings that do not contain Timezone info, and the dateutil.tz.tz.tzoffset type does not have a localize option like pytz.timezone does, which is the crux of my problem.

Am I making this too hard? Do I just replace the tzinfo in the timezone naive datetime with the dateutil.tz.tz.tzoffset object I've saved?

Code:

Below reads a date string and saves it as a datetime object, saves the timezone in a var for later use, and then converts the datestring to UTC:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as parsedate
import pytz
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

timestr = 'Sat, 5/01/2019 8:00PM EDT' #only reliable source of timezone info
dtfromstrEDT = parsedate(timestr, tzinfos=tzd) #tzd is created from the above link
mytimeZone = dtfromstrEDT.tzinfo  # save local timezone
dtUTC = dtfromstrEDT.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))  # convert to utc
```

Now here is a new timezone naive datestring. It was recorded in local time same as above (EDT) and so I want to use my saved mytimeZone var to localize it and convert to UTC. I use the standard strptime to read it in as a naive datetime. However, when using mytimeZone to localize the Naive datetime, it fails. Error below. I understand the error; but I don't know how to accomplish what I need:

```
timestrnaive = 'Mar 15 12:09:20 2019' #in EDT time, same as above string but without any timezone info
dtfromstrNaive = datetime.strptime(timestrnaive, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
dtlocalized = mytimeZone.localize(dtfromstrNaive, is_dst=True)  
# the above is where it fails with provided error below
# however I can do this instead if I had a pytz.timezone object:
loc_tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
dtlocalized = loc_tz.localize(dtfromstrNaive, is_dst=True) 
dtUTC2 = dtlocalized.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))  # convert to utc
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Examples\timezones.py", line 221, in <module>
    dtlocalized = mytimeZone.localize(dtfromstrNaive, is_dst=True)  # convert to whatever tz is stored in self.timeZone
AttributeError: 'tzoffset' object has no attribute 'localize'
```

Reviewed the following:

[Localize datetime (timezone aware) from timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304951/localize-datetime-timezone-aware-from-timezone-offset) - I am not sure how to apply that to this problem since I have a dateutil.tz.tz.tzoffset object, not the raw utc time.

[Parsing date/time string with timezone abbreviated name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703546/parsing-date-time-string-with-timezone-abbreviated-name-in-python) - This got me where I could read timezone data such as EDT and PDT.

[How to make an unaware datetime timezone aware in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python) - This does not help because it doesn't address the dateutil.tz.tz.tzoffset issue I mention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The major misconception you are harboring here is that you need the `localize` method, which is a historical artifact in `pytz` harkening from an era before PEP 495 added the "fold" attribute. You can read more about the reason that `pytz` deviates from the standard library's interface in [this article](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html).

As you note in your answer, for anything *other* than `pytz` zones, you can simply use `.replace` to construct a new datetime with the appropriate time zone. There is also a [`dateutil.utils.default_tzinfo`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/utils.html#dateutil.utils.default_tzinfo) convenience function that will automatically detect if a datetime is naive or not and attach a default value to the `tzinfo` if so.

One other thing to note is that your use of `pytz` here is unnecessary, as `dateutil` also provides a `UTC` object, so you can do something like this:

```
from dateutil import tz
timestrnaive = 'Mar 15 12:09:20 2019'
dtfromstrNaive = datetime.strptime(timestrnaive, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y") 
dtlocalized = dtfromstrNaive.replace(tzinfo=mytimeZone)
dtUTC2 = dtlocalized.astimezone(tz.UTC) # Convert to UTC
```

Thus you would not need to keep any dependency on `pytz`.

If you want to learn more about using time zones in Python, I also [recently gave a talk about this at PyCon](https://youtu.be/rz3D8VG_2TY).

Comment: Thanks. How about when I need something like this code; can I still eliminate pytz?
tz = "UTC"
mytz = pytz.timezone(tz)

Comment: Yes, `tz.gettz()` works with "UTC" and I think accepts anything that `pytz.timezone` accepts.

Answer (score 1):

After some more testing and I've realized I'm making this too hard. The solution was easy:

```
timestrnaive = 'Mar 15 12:09:20 2019'
dtfromstrNaive = datetime.strptime(timestrnaive, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y") 
dtlocalized = dtfromstrNaive.replace(tzinfo=mytimeZone)
dtUTC2 = dtlocalized.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))  # convert to utc
```